# Shuffle lists in structs nested in another list

Tags: elixir

With the following code:

```ex
[
  %Quizz{
    question: "L'unità d' Italia",
    answers: [
      %{answer: 1900, result: false},
      %{answer: 1861, result: true},
      %{answer: 1848, result: false},
    ]
  },
  %Quizz{
    question: "La Rivoluzione Francese",
    answers: [
      %{answer: 1789, result: true},
      %{answer: 1818, result: false},
      %{answer: 1766, result: false},
    ]
  },
  %Quizz{
    question: "La scoperta dell'America",
    answers: [
      %{answer: 1280, result: false},
      %{answer: 1500, result: false},
      %{answer: 1492, result: true},
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to shuffle the 3 quizz structs using `Enum.shuffle` and shuffle the list of answers for each struct. I am able to shuffle the list but I'm struggling to updated the answers list for each struct. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can shuffle the list and then map over it, replacing each `answers` field with a shuffled version of it

```
Enum.shuffle(list_of_quizzes)
|> Enum.map(fn(%{answers: answers} = quizz) -> 
    %{quizz | answers: Enum.shuffle(answers)}
end)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension:

```
for quizz <- Enum.shuffle(quizzes),
  do: %Quizz{quizz | answers: Enum.shuffle(quizz.answers)}
```

or, other way round:

```
for quizz <- Enum.shuffle(quizzes),
    answers = Enum.shuffle(quizz.answers),
  do: %Quizz{quizz | answers: answers}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`Map.update!/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#update!/3) or [`Kernel.update_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#update_in/3):

```ex
quiz_list
|> Enum.shuffle
|> Enum.map(fn q -> Map.update!(q, :answers, &Enum.shuffle/1) end)
```